# Why does Capybara insist that my hidden field is visible?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a hidden field called `user_email`. It looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="foo@bar.com" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
```

For some reason, Capybara is convinced that this is a visible element:

```
$ page.find '#user_email'
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/input">

$ page.find '#user_email', visible: :visible
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/input">

$ page.has_css? '#user_email', visible: :visible     # => true  
$ page.has_css? '#user_email', visible: false        # => true    
$ page.has_css? '#user_email', visible: true         # => true  
$ page.has_css? '#user_email', visible: :hidden      # => false   
$ page.all('#user_email').count                      # => 1
$ page.all('input[type=hidden]#user_email').count    # => 1
```

Setting `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` has no effect. I rebooted my machine to make sure I'm not crazy. Am I missing something here, or shouldn't a hidden field be, well, hidden?

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: what if you add `style='display:none'` to the tag? (It doesn't make much sense to not being able to find hidden input fields though. What if you hide the entire form with CSS?)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't responded to what driver you're using, but it looks like the default rack_test driver has a bug where it incorrectly considers hidden type inputs to be visible.  A fix has been added in the master branch of Capybara.  The selenium driver correctly considers it invisible -- not sure about the other drivers available (capybara-webkit, poltergeist, etc)

Comment: My Javascript driver is Poltergeist; however, this isn't in a `js: true` test, so I'm not sure how that works -- does it use Poltergeist or the default rack_test?

Comment: @Sasgorilla if not in a js test and you haven't changed Capybara.default_driver then it's using rack_test (which doesn't process most CDs) Give the master branch of capybara a try  it should fix your issue